# datePicker in UIPopover after tapping on UITextField iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I would like to create `UIPopover` on iPad with a `UIDatePicker` within it, after tapping on `UITextField`.

I used the code below to do so but I don't know what `tempButton.frame` represents or what `tempButton` is.

Is it possible to do the same using storyboard? Thanks in Advance.

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverContent release];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame
```

Comment: tempButton is the custom button which is placed on UITextfield. So, that when you tap on button popover appears.

Comment: @darshana Thanks Darshana finally got it to work .But how to get the value selected I mean result method.Currently its crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the button itself, you can use the [rightView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW27) property of [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).

And using a stroryboard for the datepicker view can be done as well.

1) Drag a ViewController to the storyboard.

2) Set it's class to your custom class in the Identity Inspector.

3) Set a value for "StoryBoard ID" in the Identity Inspector.

4) Setup the view with your datePicker.

5) #import "PopoverContentViewController.h" to your presenting ViewController.

When you present your popover:

```
PopoverContentViewController *popoverContent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myStoryboardID"];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:myTextField.myRightView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

You'll probably want to setup a delegate so the `UIDatePicker` can communicate back to the presenting `ViewController`.

Comment: Thank you Sir.But I have few doubts I cannot set the custom class in identity inspector .Please can you state a bit more clearly like whats in PopoverContentViewController.h and about custom class .Thanks very much would really appreciate the help.Sorry for the trouble Sir.

Comment: When I drag & drop datePicker in ipad it covers the entire width I only want date picker in the view how do I do that ?

Comment: Jacob, your custom class needs to be a subclass of UIViewController, or else it won't let you set it in the identity inspector. So when you make your custom class, make sure and select UIViewController from the "subclass of" option.

Comment: I am still confused . I have created a new project and it already has a view controller so I dragged and dropped uitextfield into it .I dragged and dropped another viewcontoller in storyboard and    dragged and dropped datePicker But I did not see ant subclass in identity inspector .Now I dont really know what to do. I am really sorry.Should I accept this answer and post another question on the same ?

Comment: Jacob, I'll explain further when I get back home. Limited on my mobile device to comments at the moment.